# Sum of odd numbers, greater than zero, generates a new term. How?

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{\text{odd }k} \frac{-2e^{-ikt}}{ik\pi} = \sum_{\text{odd }k>0} \frac{-2e^{-ikt}+2e^{ikt}}{ik\pi}$$

How does limiting all $k$ values to greater than zero, introduce the new term in the numerator?

I've been staring at this for an hour and I can't for the life of me figure out how positive $k$'s allow for a new term.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: On the left you have all odd integers, odd and even. You get the right by pairing off $k$ with $-k$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: You probably meant *"positive and negative"*

Comment: They aren't new terms.  They are the old *negative* terms.  But now added to the positive terms.  Basically you are just combining the positive and negative terms together.

Comment: Restricting to positive *eliminates* half of the terms.  You add those that were eliminated back to the ones that were left.  The "new" terms are just the "old" terms that were eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{k \text{ odd}} a_k= $

$\sum\limits_{k \text{ odd }>0} a_k + \sum\limits_{k \text{ odd }<0} a_k=$

$\sum\limits_{k \text{ odd }>0} a_k + \sum\limits_{k \text{ odd }>0} a_{-k}=$

$\sum\limits_{k\text{ odd} > 0} (a_k + a_{-k})$

======

In this case if $j = -k < 0$ and $k = |j| = - j> 0$.

Then $\frac{-2e^{-ijt}}{ij\pi}=\frac{-2e^{ikt}}{-ik\pi} =\frac{2e^{ikt}}{ik\pi}$

So $\sum\limits_{k = \pm M} \frac{-2e^{-ikt}}{ik\pi}=$

$\sum\limits_{k = M}\frac{-2e^{-ikt}}{ik\pi} + \sum\limits_{k = -M}\frac{-2e^{-ikt}}{ik\pi}$

$\sum\limits_{k = M}\frac{-2e^{-ikt}}{ik\pi} + \sum\limits_{k = M}\frac{2e^{ikt}}{ik\pi}$

$\sum\limits_{k = M}(\frac{-2e^{-ikt}}{ik\pi}+ \frac{2e^{ikt}}{ik\pi})$

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel kinda foolish, but I'm glad I understand it now.

Comment: Feeling foolish is par for the course.